# Juno not waking up from sleep

Tags: release-juno, suspend

I'm having an issue when trying to wake up my laptop from sleep.

It shows this:

[image: laptop after "waking up"]

Also, nothing works, I have tried put my password to unlock but the system frezees, so, if you have any idea of how to solve this will be great.

This is my hardware info:

- Dual-Core AMD A12-9720P
- RADEON R7, 12 COMPUTE CORES 4C+8G
- Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Wani [Radeon R5/R6/R7 Graphics] (rev c8)